# How to add a literal without using <br>

Tags: html, css

I use this code to add the actual browser I use to my paragraph with id=browser further down

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#browser").text('sBrowser');
});
```

The problem is that my paragraph with `id=browser` is positioned one row too low.

Further down I have this markup

```
<div id="info">
    Torsdag : <time>2013-09-05 16:00:00</time>
    <p id="browser"></p>
</div>
```

I want the markup paragraph with `id=browser` to be positioned just below this row

```
Torsdag : <time>2013-09-05 16:00:00</time>
```

without any empty row in between

When I run this markup in IE 9 I get this result as you can see I have an empty above `sBrowser`

> Torsdag : 2013-09-05 16:00:00
>
> sBrowser

I want it to look like this instead

> ```
> Torsdag : 2013-09-05 16:00:00
> sBrowser
> ```

So what do I have to change to get the look that I want.

Here is the complete markup and css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>Kontaktuppgifter</title>
      <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="js/flygbolag.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

         $(function ()  //wait until the DOM is complete
         {
            $("#browser").text('sBrowser');
         });

      </script>

      <style type = "text/css">
         body
         {
            font-size:small;
            width:72em;
            background : #87a5be url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat right bottom fixed;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            margin:0.2em auto;
          }

          header #info
          {
             font-size:120%;
             float:right; 
             font-weight:bold;
          }
      </style>   
  </head>

  <body id="kontakt">
     <header>
        <div>
           <div id="info">
              Torsdag : <time>2013-09-05 16:00:00</time> <br />
              <p id="browser"></p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </header>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have your tried `<span id="browser"></span>` rather than a paragraph? `p` adds a line of its own methinks.

Comment: By “literal”, you seem to mean “line break.” And it seems that you want to cause a forced line break without causing anything else, which is what the `br` element is for, but the title of the question says “without using `<br>`”. Yet your code sample has `<br>`.

Comment: Why not use a div instead of a paragraph? Alternatively reduce the margin and padding of your paragraph element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding to your **CSS**:

```
p#browser{
    margin:0;
    padding:0; /* only if needed... */
}
```

[BEFORE](http://jsbin.com/AyiROXO/1/edit) and [**AFTER**](http://jsbin.com/AyiROXO/3/edit)

And BTW the `<br>` you use - **is not needed**, as `<p>` is already a **block**-level element (if not strictly defined as *inline* or *inline-block*)

---

What you might need also (instead) is a nice small CSS reset like e.g:
 http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Why use `p` and then style away its default margins when you can decide which element you have? And why recommend CSS reset snake-oil that would remove all kinds of default styling, causing various problems, when you have mentioned the way to remove the specific styling that causes the problem?

Comment: @jukka P was in the original html markup, thats why I decided to point out the real issue and the fix without touching HTML. Using DIV is also a solution. And a CSS reset... (I dont say its always handy but..) dont tell me you never used it. Even Boorstrap uses it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div id="info">Torsdag :
        <time>2013-09-05 16:00:00</time>
        <br /> <span id="browser"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

as here: http://jsfiddle.net/psQJg/

---

EDIT alternately: CSS as

```
#info,#browser {float:left;}
```

markup as:

```
<div>
    <div id="info">Torsdag :
        <time>2013-09-05 16:00:00</time>
        <span id="browser"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/psQJg/1/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the real problem is just that you are using the `p` element without taking into account that it has default top (and bottom) margin. The best solution is to use an element that has no such default rendering, namely `div`. You won’t need (and shouldn’t use) the `br` then, because `div` is rendered as a block, starting from a new line.

```
       <div id="info">
          Torsdag : <time>2013-09-05 16:00:00</time>
          <div id="browser"></div>
       </div>
```